# chunk.sortModules is not a function when running npm command

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

I just need to revive an old project in order to modify it.
I did `git checkout 0.0.2` that's the tag that is running on production right now, so I don't know why is not working.

I downloaded the code to my PC did `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` `npm install`
but I'm facing this error when doing

```
npm run dev
```

or any other npm run command

```sh
/node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:188
            chunk.sortModules();
                  ^

TypeError: chunk.sortModules is not a function
```

here is my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "eslint": "^4.19.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "flickity": "^2.2.0",
        "proptypes": "^1.1.0",
        "react-read-more-less": "^0.1.6",
        "react-spinners": "^0.5.4",
        "wow.js": "^1.2.2"
    }
}
```

I don't have any webpack.config.js file

only this **webpack.mix.js**

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery', 'window.$', 'jquery', 'window.jquery']
});

mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

Node version: v8.4.0
NPM version: 5.3.0

I think i should just modify one lib but i don't know which one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate your issue on my local by utilizing the files you provided

**Solution 1: (WORKS)**

Assumes you want to stay on same version of `lavarel-mix` to avoid any build errors with production

Lock your lavaler-mix version in package.json. Note how i removed the caret (^). You can then just do `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json; npm install` after making the below edit in your package.json file.

```
"laravel-mix": "2.0"
```

**Solution 2 (DOESN'T WORK):**

Assumes you don't care about your lavarel version compatibility.

Install latest version that you feel comfortable with

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest -D
```

This one gets following error when tested with your sample files above

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
```

NOTE: Solution 2 could work but you will need to most likely update your webpack.mix.js config to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `"laravel-mix"` version is very low.

Try to install the latest version to see if it fix your problem.

```sh
npm install laravel-mix@latest -D
```